# No other way than dropping the duplicates, if ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape?

Tags: dataset, reshape, valueerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax1fz.png)

Hi everyone, this is my first question.

I'm working on a dataset from patients who undergone urine analysis.
Every row refer to a single Patient Id and every Request ID could refer to different types of urine analysis (aspect, colour, number of erythrocytes, bacteria and go on).
I've add an image to let you understand my dataset.

I'd like to reshape making one request = one row , with all the tests done in the same request on the same row.
After that I want to merge with another df, that I reshape by Request ID (cause the first was missing a "long result" column, that I downloaded from another software in use in our Hospital).

I've tried:

df_pivot = df.pivot(index='Id Richiesta', columns = 'Nome Analisi Elementare', values = 'Risultato')

df_pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)

After I want to do  -->   df_merge = pd.merge (df_pivot,df,how='left', on='Id Richiesta')

I've tried once with another dataset, but I had to drop_duplicates for other purpose, and it worked.
But this time I have to analyse all the features.

How can I do? Is there no other way than dropping the duplicates?

Thank you for any help!   :)

Answer (score 0):

I've studied more my data and discovered 1 duplicate of bacteria for the same id request (1 in almost 8 million entries....)

```
df.drop_duplicates[df[['Id Richiesta', 'Id Analisi Elementare', 'Risultato']].duplicated()]
```

Then visualized all the rows referring at the "Id Richiesta" and the keep last (they were the same).

Thank you and sorry.
Please, tell me if I had to delete this question.